# LiveReload not working Guard (Firefox)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, guard

I'm having a fun issue, I have LiveReload working in Chrome, so I know it's installed right, but I can't for the life of me get it going on Firefox 9.0.1.  I activate the icon on my site and it just stays red, with the following symptom showing in my guard terminal.

```
Browser connected.
Browser URL: {"command":"hello","protocols":["http://livereload.com/protocols/connection-check-1"]}
Browser disconnected.
```

Here's my guardfile.

```
guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{app/.+\.(erb|haml)})
  watch(%r{app/helpers/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{(public/|app/assets).+\.(css|js|html)})
  watch(%r{(app/assets/.+\.css)\.s[ac]ss}) { |m| m[1] }
  watch(%r{(app/assets/.+\.js)\.coffee}) { |m| m[1] }
  watch(%r{config/locales/.+\.yml})
end
```

I did some research on the subject and all I can find are people reporting issues and then reporting back that it just cleared up, without any explanation from the developers.  Fun!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Latest Firefox seems to be unable to inject chrome:// urls into the host page unlees the corresponding resource has additional "contentaccesible" manifest attribute.

I've added that and submitted a pull request: https://github.com/livereload/livereload-extensions/pull/8

You can grab the fixed plugin package here: https://github.com/downloads/siasia/livereload-extensions/LiveReload-2.0.9.xpi

Comment: Thanks. But for me it's not even working with latest addon version for Chrome. Do you have any working chrome version? I mean, it works for CSS and html changes only...and for javascript which is written inside html directly...

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat. Have you tried using the non-browswer extension method:

http://help.livereload.com/kb/general-use/using-livereload-without-browser-extensions

...also, you can use the following gem to automatically inject the script in your test environment:

https://github.com/johnbintz/rack-livereload

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem with Chrome.
But it was an error on my part I was accessing my file from:

```
file:///path/to/myFile.html
```

So I just setup a webserver to read my file from:

```
http://localhost/myFile.html
```

and then livereload connected.