# How to write JavasScript project using guard-livereload?

Tags: javascript, ruby, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, guard

I would like to start learn JS.
I found gem guard-livereload.

In my Rails apps it works great. But I would like to use it to reload local files for simple JS scripts.

so I installed `guard-livereload` to rvm gemset global. Created new dir `javascript`
added to `Guardfile`

```
# https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload
guard :livereload do
  watch(%r{.+\.(html|css|js)$})
end
```

opened Chrome with Livereload extension(1.6)

This is from my console:

```
> guard                                                                                                                                                                    /Users/rege/Code/javascript 1.9.3p194 @
Guard could not detect any of the supported notification libraries.
Guard is now watching at '/Users/rege/Code/javascript'
LiveReload 1.6 is waiting for a browser to connect.
Browser connected.
Browser URL: file://localhost/Users/rege/Code/javascript/examples/example_1_2.html
Reloading browser: examples/example_1_2.html
Reloading browser: examples/example_1_2.html
Reloading browser: examples/example_1_2.html
```

My Guard version:

```
> gem list guard                                                                                                                                                           /Users/rege/Code/javascript 1.9.3p194 @

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

guard (1.3.0)
guard-livereload (1.0.0)
```

All seems works but Chrome doesn`t refresh page.

Comment: It also doesn't work for me. I've found this add-on for Firefox which works also for JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710613/livereload-not-working-guard-firefox

Comment: Your question helped me to use livereload, thanks! (I didn't know I had to run `guard` command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome you have to explicitly give extensions permissions to file urls. Right click on the LiveReload icon, go to manage extensions, and give LiveReload permissions to file urls.